# Combining two warpAffine, shift and rotate image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I currently use the following sequence of code to first shift an image, then rotate the same image:

```
M = np.float32([[1,0,20],[0,1,10]])
shifted = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(y_size,x_size),flags=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
center_of_rot = (500, 500)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center_of_rot, 1.23, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(shifted, M, (y_size, x_size),flags=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
```

I think it's possible to somehow multiply the two matrices and only do one operation instead of two warpAffine, I am looking for some guidance since I really suck at math.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to multiply the matrices. Add third row [0,0,1] to the 2x3 matrices. This is called homogeneous coordinates.

```
M = np.float32([[1,0,20],[0,1,10],[0,0,1]]) // shift matrix
center_of_rot = (500, 500)
Rot = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center_of_rot, 1.23, 1.0)
Rot = np.vstack([Rot, [0,0,1]])
TransfomMatrix = np.matmul(M, Rot)
rotated = cv2.warpPerspective(img, TransformMatrix, (y_size, x_size),flags=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4) //  note - warpPerspective is used here, because the matrix is now 3x3 not 3x2
```